# Android phone images are not the correct resolution

Tags: images, hardware

My android phone has an 8 megapixel camera meaning the resolution of the images should be 3,264 x 2,448. However when i plug my phone into my computer and view the details of the pictures, some are 1920 x 1080 but most of them are 1280 x 720. If someone could explain why this is happening that would be great.

Comment: There is a tradeoff between image resolution and filesize (you can store more pictures if they're smaller).  There is likely a setting to select what resolution to save the images at.

Comment: wow I feel so stupid it was right there in the settings. post that as an answer so i can give you credit.

Comment: The question is off-topic, so I'd rather not post an answer.  But glad we were able to solve your problem.